# Why can't I retrieve data from an mdb file in Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: c#, windows, ms-access

I recently bought a software that uses an mdb file for data storage. I don't like the software's reporting and statement generation that much so I decided to write my own reporting program using VS 2008's C#.

So my program accesses the mdb file that comes with the software I just bought. My dev environment is Windows XP. My deployment environment is Windows 7 64-bit. In my dev machine, I can retrieve records from the mdb file just fine but when I deploy the program to a Windows 7 64-bit machine, it cannot read the records from the mdb file. No errors are thrown, it just can't get that data.

I also tried installing VS 2012 on the deployment machine (Win 7 64-bit) and imported my VS2008 project there. Same issues, can't get records from that mdb file (again, no errors are thrown).

Please help?

edit 1: I just tried backing up the mdb using the purchased software backup utility. I can retrieve records from that backed up mdb. I wonder if the software is trying to modify my access to the mdb file.

edit 2: I don't think the software is trying to modify my access to the mdb file because when deployed to my xp machine, I can access the mdb file just fine.

edit 3: I'm beginning to suspect this is a file security feature within Windows 7.

edit 4: If I copy the mdb file and access that copied mdb file, it returns 0 rows. If I back it up using the software's backup utility, it returns the exact rows I expect.

Comment: Please show us a piece of your code ([a short but complete example](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html)) and describe *exactly* what happens. (E.g. `In this line, Console.WriteLine(myDataTable.Rows.Count) prints 0 although it should be 15.`)

Comment: Are you sure that "no errors are thrown", or could it be a case where you `catch` exception(s) but don't handle them properly (e.g., just suppress them)?

Comment: @GordThompson, Yes, I'm sure. I don't suppress the catch. Please check my edit above. I discovered something new to the issue.

Comment: @Heinzi: Sorry, but pasting code wouldn't help. As I said, there are no errors thrown. Also, I've tried that Console.Writeline thingy. Yes, it prints 0 although it should be more than 0 :)

 Please check my edit above. I discovered something new to the issue.

Comment: You say "no errors are thrown", do you mean that queries return 0 rows, or do you mean that you have try/catch with empty catch blocks strewn around that makes you believe there are no errors?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: the queries return 0 rows.

Comment: Where is the MDB file located?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: C:/Program Files (x86)/<software name>/data/my.mdb

Comment: Please check, I already made 4 edits above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're running up against security features of Windows.

Programs are no longer allowed to change files under the program files directories, unless they run with elevated access.

What happens is that a feature called [Virtual Store](https://superuser.com/questions/46731/strange-possible-shadow-copy-issue-where-two-editors-show-different-contents) kicks in and creates private (for your user) copies of the file somewhere else, under your user profile.

Most likely the software has created an empty database file under the user profile, and is accessing that instead.

You can not place writable files in the program files any more, the program needs to be either redesigned or installed somewhere else, like under the user profile where it would have write access.

Comment: How can I assign elevated access to my own program?

Comment: You shouldn't. Move the database or the program. In any case I have no idea, I assume you need to modify a manifest file for your program but I don't write software that require this normally.

Comment: Yeh, MS security - pfat! I - as admin on my dev machine - am not allowed to make changes to some files I created in some locations. Ridiculous! There are work-arounds, but it's friggin annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Set your target platform to "x86" instead of "Any cpu" to be sure that you are running it 32-bit.

Comment: I did this already. Same issues. Please check my edit above. Thanks.